# How can I separate this code for greater clarity?

Tags: android

I made a Memory Game for Android.

**My problem is that all the code is in one class. So I need to separate the code with a new class to help make it more clear.**

This is the code:

```
public class NivelA extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private int [] fichasIds = {
        R.drawable.img_1,
        R.drawable.img_2,
        R.drawable.img_3,
        R.drawable.img_4,
        R.drawable.img_5,
        R.drawable.img_6,
        R.drawable.imgOculto,   
};

protected int[] fichas;

private ImageView[] imageviews;

private static final int cantFichas = 6;

private int fichasUp;

private int currentIndex = -1;

private int lastIndex = -1;

private int fichasIguales = 0;

private int vidas = 3;
private TextView vidas_txt;

Handler handler;

private int [] imgIds = {
        R.id.img_1,
        R.id.img_2,
        R.id.img_3,
        R.id.img_4,
        R.id.img_5,
        R.id.img_6,
        R.id.img_7,
        R.id.img_8,
        R.id.img_9,
        R.id.img_10,
        R.id.img_11,
        R.id.img_12,
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.nivel1);

    //Toast
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(NivelA.this, "Nivel: 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 65);
    toast.show();

    handler = new Handler ();

    fichasIguales = 0;

    vidas_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vidas_iguales);

    fichas = new int [12];

    for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        fichas[i] = -1;
    }

    imageviews = new ImageView [imgIds.length];
    for (int i=0; i<imgIds.length; i++)
    {

        imageviews[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(imgIds[i]);
    }

    Random random = new Random ();

    for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
        for (int z=0; z<2; z++)
        {
            int fichasRandom = random.nextInt(12);
            while (fichas[fichasRandom]!= -1)
            {
                fichasRandom = random.nextInt(12);
            }
            fichas[fichasRandom]= i;
        }
    }

    //Los listener
    for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        ((ImageView)findViewById(imgIds[i])).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        ((ImageView)findViewById(imgIds[i])).setImageResource(R.drawable.imgOculto);
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int index = Integer.parseInt((String)v.getTag());

    for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        if (v.getId() == imgIds [i])
        {
            index = i;
            ((ImageView)findViewById(imgIds[i])).setImageResource(fichasIds[fichas[i]]);

            imageviews[i].setFocusable(false);
            imageviews[i].setClickable(false);
            break;
        }
    }
    fichasUp++;

    if (fichasUp == 2)
    {
        vidas--;
        vidas_txt.setText(String.valueOf(vidas));

        currentIndex = index;

        for (ImageView view:imageviews)
        {
            view.setFocusable(false);
            view.setClickable(false);
        }

        fichasUp = 0;
        handler.postDelayed(fichasOcultas, 1000);

    }
    else{
        lastIndex = index;
    }

}

Runnable fichasOcultas = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (fichas[currentIndex]== fichas[lastIndex])
        {
            ((ImageView)findViewById(imgIds[lastIndex])).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ((ImageView)findViewById(imgIds[currentIndex])).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            fichasIguales ++;


            //Toast [ Hay Coincidencia ]
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(NivelA.this, "Hay Coincidencia!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER, 14, 0);
            toast.show();

            if (fichasIguales == cantFichas)
            {
                win ();
            }
        }else
        {
            ((ImageView)findViewById(imgIds[currentIndex])).setImageResource(R.drawable.imgOculto);
            ((ImageView)findViewById(imgIds[lastIndex])).setImageResource(R.drawable.imgOculto);
        }


        for (ImageView view:imageviews)
        {
            view.setFocusable(true);
            view.setClickable(true);
        }
    }

};
protected void win() {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(NivelA.this, "Ganaste!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you move all your game logic out of the `NivelA` class. That should go a long way toward simplifying your code. In general, each `Activity` subclass should be responsible for creating the screen, perhaps responding to events, and not much else.

Also, instead of making `NivelA` implement `OnClickListener`, you might want to use the `android:onClick` attribute that views can have. If you assign a view the attribute

```
android:onClick="aClickMethod"
```

then you just need to implement a public method:

```
public void aClickMethod(View view) { . . . }
```

(The name of the method is totally up to you.) Assigning the `android:onClick` method automatically makes the view clickable. You'll be surprised how much code will be eliminated with this trick.

Comment: So If a put the android:onClick in the ImageViews I will have to eliminate a part of the code?

Comment: @Azrael94 - If you use `android.onClick`, you don't _need_ part of your code. You don't need to find the view and set an `OnClickListener`. Just put the logic current in your `onClick` method into the method named in the xml file.

Comment: Oh Thansk! But another problem that I have is that I need to do with differents classes for aprove and understand all about Thread-Runnable-etc. So if you can help me with that it will be awesome

Comment: @Azrael94 - When you have a specific programming problem, post it as another question and you should get plenty of help. Remember, though, that this forum is for asking specific questions, not to ask for general tutorial information. For threads and runnables, you might want to start with the [Java tutorial on concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Comment: Ok thanks I will try to create a new class that extends Runnable and see If that could work